# ApacHE Nifi with docker: how to integrate NARs for custom processors

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

[This](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile) is official Apache NiFi docker file.

I want to build my own custom docker file for Apache NiFi(ie using some official nifi image).

In normal way of working(ie without containers), we normally copy our custom processor NARs in lib folder of the distribution.

In case of dockerization, how do I integrate my custom NARs?

Comment: Did you try: `RUN cd extensions; \ curl  custom-url-where-is-nar-bundle -O;`